# How to remove the duedate from an Issue using Jira REST API

Tags: python, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to remove the `duedate` from an Issue using Jira's REST API, but it keeps setting the `duedate` to **today**.

I have tried with with the Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library as well as the [jira-python](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package.

Here are snippets of both.

**requests**

```
import requests

jira_issue_key = 'PROJECT-1234'

requests.put(
    url='http://localhost:8000/issue/%s/' % jira_issue_key, cookies=cookies,
    json={'fields': {"duedate": None}})
```

**jira-python**

```
import os
from jira import JIRA

username = 'username'
password = os.environ['PASSWORD']

jira = JIRA('https://localhost:8000', auth=(username, password))

issue = jira.issue(jira_issue_key)
issue.update(fields={"duedate": None})
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you tried using `"duedate": null` (or "null") instead of None?

Comment: I ask because JSON has no concept of None, nor will the sql database at the jira end.

Comment: @Alan the above example get's converted to JSON. I haven't tried a raw JSON curl request through. In Python, "null" would be converted to the JSON string "null", but `None` get's converted to JSON `null`

Comment: Yes, json.dumps converts to null. Put and get for requests though: "Note that any dictionary key whose value is None will not be added to the URL's query string." (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: Otherwise - shot in the dark - does the server have duedate configured as a mandatory field and/or have a duedate trigger? Last time I set up a service desk I put in a trigger and you only entered as date if you want to override the default.